# select concat(min(released_year), ' and it\'\s ', pages where released_year min(released_year),

Tags: mysql

what i want to do is to get the number of pages for this writer be

I have written a code and have a problem the code is:

```
select concat(author_fname, ' ', author_lname, ' have released his firest book at ', min(released_year), ' and it\'\s ', pages where released_year min(released_year), ' pages') as 'info' from books group by author_lname, author_fname;
```

```
(ERROR 1064 (42000): You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near ', ' ', pages where released_year = min(released_year))as 'info' from books grou' at line 1)
```

the table:

```
+---------+-----------------------------------------------------+--------------+----------------+---------------+----------------+-------+
| book_id | title                                               | author_fname | author_lname   | released_year | stock_quantity | pages |
+---------+-----------------------------------------------------+--------------+----------------+---------------+----------------+-------+
|       1 | The Namesake                                        | Jhumpa       | Lahiri         |          2003 |             32 |   291 |
|       2 | Norse Mythology                                     | Neil         | Gaiman         |          2016 |             43 |   304 |
|       3 | American Gods                                       | Neil         | Gaiman         |          2001 |             12 |   465 |
|       4 | Interpreter of Maladies                             | Jhumpa       | Lahiri         |          1996 |             97 |   198 |
|       5 | A Hologram for the King: A Novel                    | Dave         | Eggers         |          2012 |            154 |   352 |
|       6 | The Circle                                          | Dave         | Eggers         |          2013 |             26 |   504 |
|       7 | The Amazing Adventures of Kavalier & Clay           | Michael      | Chabon         |          2000 |             68 |   634 |
|       8 | Just Kids                                           | Patti        | Smith          |          2010 |             55 |   304 |
|       9 | A Heartbreaking Work of Staggering Genius           | Dave         | Eggers         |          2001 |            104 |   437 |
|      10 | Coraline                                            | Neil         | Gaiman         |          2003 |            100 |   208 |
|      11 | What We Talk About When We Talk About Love: Stories | Raymond      | Carver         |          1981 |             23 |   176 |
|      12 | Where I'm Calling From: Selected Stories            | Raymond      | Carver         |          1989 |             12 |   526 |
|      13 | White Noise                                         | Don          | DeLillo        |          1985 |             49 |   320 |
|      14 | Cannery Row                                         | John         | Steinbeck      |          1945 |             95 |   181 |
|      15 | Oblivion: Stories                                   | David        | Foster Wallace |          2004 |            172 |   329 |
|      16 | Consider the Lobster                                | David        | Foster Wallace |          2005 |             92 |   343 |
|      17 | 10% Happier                                         | Dan          | Harris         |          2014 |             29 |   256 |
|      18 | fake_book                                           | Freida       | Harris         |          2001 |            287 |   428 |
|      19 | Lincoln In The Bardo                                | George       | Saunders       |          2017 |           1000 |   367 |
+---------+-----------------------------------------------------+--------------+----------------+---------------+----------------+-------+
```

Comment: can you show the table so that we can help you better

Comment: What is the problem? What error are you getting?

Comment: i'm a new user and i don't know how to post a picture, can you please tell me how @JavierG.Raya

Comment: Please post as text

Comment: the error is (ERROR 1064 (42000): You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near ', ' ',  pages where released_year = min(released_year))as 'info' from books grou' at line 1) @Kendle

Comment: do you mean the table @Kendle

Comment: fix: `, 'pages where released_year ', min(released_year),` and that solves your issue. Your error is caused by not having the corract parts of your CONCAT statement quoted.

Answer (score 0):

I think that this is what you need.
As we do not have the table definition nor sample data it is a bit complicated.

> ```
> create table books(
> author_fname varchar(25),
> author_lname varchar(25),
> pages int,
> released_year int);
> ```
>
> ```
> ✓
> ```

> ```
> select 
> concat(
>   author_fname, 
>   ' ', 
>   author_lname, 
>   ' have released his firest book at ',
>   min(released_year), 
>   ' and it''s ', 
>   pages,
>   ' were released_year ',
>   min(released_year), 
>   ' pages') as "info" 
> from books 
> group by 
>   author_lname, 
>   author_fname,
>   pages;
> ```

> ```
> | info |
> | :--- |
> ```

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_5.7&fiddle=61e11e00b2e56aa637926fcf3360d6a0)*

Comment: @Martin we can escape with `\'` or `''` : both work. This runs OK in DBfiddle.